Spring Boot - No X.509 certificate for client authentication, use empty Certificate message instead
Trying to hit an external API which require certificate but getting the following error:
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|52|http-nio-8080-exec-2|2024-06-19 20:19:22.887 IST|CertificateRequest.java:767|Unsupported authentication scheme: dsa_sha256
javax.net.ssl|ALL|52|http-nio-8080-exec-2|2024-06-19 20:19:22.887 IST|X509Authentication.java:223|No X.509 cert selected for [EC, EdDSA, RSASSA-PSS, RSA, DSA]
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|52|http-nio-8080-exec-2|2024-06-19 20:19:22.887 IST|CertificateRequest.java:817|No available authentication scheme
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|52|http-nio-8080-exec-2|2024-06-19 20:19:22.887 IST|ServerHelloDone.java:151|Consuming ServerHelloDone handshake message (
<empty>
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|52|http-nio-8080-exec-2|2024-06-19 20:19:22.888 IST|CertificateMessage.java:299|No X.509 certificate for client authentication, use empty Certificate message instead
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|52|http-nio-8080-exec-2|2024-06-19 20:19:22.888 IST|CertificateMessage.java:330|Produced client Certificate handshake message (
"Certificates": <empty list>
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|52|http-nio-8080-exec-2|2024-06-19 20:19:22.896 IST|ECDHClientKeyExchange.java:407|Produced ECDHE ClientKeyExchange handshake message (
"ECDH ClientKeyExchange": {
  "ecdh public": {

Definition of RestTemplate looks like this:
@Configuration
public class SSLRestTemplate {

    @Value("${trust.store.path}")
    private Resource trustStore;

    @Value("${trust.store.password}")
    private String trustStorePassword;

    @Bean(name = "sslRestTemplate")
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, CertificateException, MalformedURLException, IOException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
        SSLContext sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder()
                .loadTrustMaterial(trustStore.getURL(), trustStorePassword.toCharArray()).build();
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);
        HttpClientConnectionManager cm = PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerBuilder.create()
                .setSSLSocketFactory(sslConFactory)
                .build();
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setConnectionManager(cm).build();
        ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
        return new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
    }

}

application.yml is as follows:
....

trust:
  store:
    path: "classpath:keystore/cert.jks"
    password: "password"
....

cert.jks is stored in resources/keystore directory.
I created cert.jks from crt file and key file using openssl.
What am I doing wrong?

You are loading the certificate into the 'trust store' rather than the 'key store'. The 'trust store' is used for you as the client to authenticate the server. The 'key store' is needed so that the server can authenticate you.
I have not tried running your code but you might try something like this:

@Configuration
public class SSLRestTemplate {

    @Value("${key.store.path}")
    private Resource keyStore;

    @Value("${key.store.password}")
    private String keyStorePassword;
 
    @Bean(name = "sslRestTemplate")
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, CertificateException, MalformedURLException, IOException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
        SSLContext sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder()
                .loadKeyMaterial(keyStore.getURL(), keyStorePassword.toCharArray()).build();
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);
        HttpClientConnectionManager cm = PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerBuilder.create()
                .setSSLSocketFactory(sslConFactory)
                .build();
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setConnectionManager(cm).build();
        ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
        return new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
    }
}


and edit your application.yml:
....

key:
  store:
    path: "classpath:keystore/cert.jks"
    password: "password"
....


This article from DZone was useful in writing this answer, and also has a tip on how to test your key store by writing a trust strategy which doesn't bother to authenticate the server.

I wasn't able to getURL() method on keystore. So I modified it like this. It is still not working. Also, can you point me to some good resource which explains jargons like keystore, trust store. I am prettly confused at this point.

do I have to add cert to trust store also?

I think you have to make your pastebin resource public because I got a 403 when I tried to look at it. No, you don't have to add the certificate to your trust store because it doesn't contain any public keys for authenticating servers. According to this answer your usual root certificate is provided by default if you don't specify a trust store so you should be fine. I haven't found a better resource than that DZone article: it has some links to the original Oracle material but I think that's more difficult to read than the article.

Thanks for the help. It's resolved now.
